# Beamer: block in minipage/columns are out of the page

Tags: beamer, minipage, block

When I add a block in beamer inside a minipage, I have a block that is bigger than the minipage instead of a block that fits into the minipage. So this gives me really strange alignements:

[image]

Any idea?

Thanks !

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{My slide}
  \begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
    \begin{exampleblock}{My title}
    Hello, I'm an example block with several lines on the left part of my slide.
    \end{exampleblock}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.7\linewidth}
    Hello, I'm a classical text with several lines on the right part of my slide.
  \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use `columns`, the issue does not arise.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{My slide}
 \begin{columns}
  \begin{column}{.3\linewidth}
    \begin{exampleblock}{My title}
    Hello, I'm an example block with several lines on the left part of my slide.
    \end{exampleblock}
  \end{column}%
  \begin{column}{.7\linewidth}
    Hello, I'm a classical text with several lines on the right part of my slide.
  \end{column}
 \end{columns} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]